# Not able to update multiple record with reference to sub object _id in mongodb nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update other table value with change on master table.
My model is:

```
var model = new Schema({
   client:{
      _id: Object,
      companyName: String,
   },
   branchName: String,
});
```

My node js code is:

```
var objBranch = require('../models/branchMSTModel');
objBranch.findOneAndUpdate({ "client._id": doc._id }, { $set: { "client.companyName": doc.companyName } }, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

In this "doc" is object with all value.
i want to update company name where "_id" match with "doc._id".

Answer (score 0):

```
objBranch.findOneAndUpdate({ "client._id": doc._id }, { $set: { "client.companyName": doc.companyName } }, {new: true} ,function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

you can try using new : true, it fetches the documents with the new changes in it.